# Segmentation fault when running binaries compiled using riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc in spike

Tags: riscv

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int src = 5;
int dst = 0;

asm ("mv %0,%1":"=X"(dst):"r"(src));
asm("mv a0,a1");

printf(" %d\n", dst);
return 0;
}
```

prashantravi@ubuntu:~/rocket-chip$ riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o asm_test asm_test.c
prashantravi@ubuntu:~/rocket-chip$ spike riscv/bin/pk asm_test
z  0000000000000000 ra 0000000000000000 sp 00000000fefffb50 gp 0000000000801fb8
tp 0000000000000000 t0 0000000000000000 t1 0000000000000008 t2 00000000008012e0
s0 0000000000000000 s1 0000000000000000 a0 0000000000800430 a1 0000000000000001
a2 00000000fefffb58 a3 0000000000800484 a4 0000000000800514 a5 0000000000000000
a6 00000000fefffb50 a7 0000000000000000 s2 0000000000000000 s3 0000000000000000
s4 0000000000000000 s5 0000000000000000 s6 0000000000000000 s7 0000000000000000
s8 0000000000000000 s9 0000000000000000 sA 0000000000000000 sB 0000000000000000
t3 ffffffffffffffff t4 0000000000000000 t5 0000000000000000 t6 0000000000000000
pc fffffffffffffffe va fffffffffffffffe insn       ffffffff sr 8000000000003008
User fetch segfault @ 0xfffffffffffffffe

I am getting the above error when i am compiling programs using riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc in spike.

The same code executes perfectly when run with riscv64-unknown-elf gcc

Comment: What are you running them on?

Comment: Please edit to show a minimum code example that reproduces the problem. It's not possible to even guess without it.

Comment: @slebetman i am running the binaries on spike ISA simulator on linux

Comment: " i am running the binaries on spike ISA simulator on linux"? You're prompt says you're running them on the proxy-kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run dynamically linked programs on the proxy-kernel.

You must statically link your programs if you are going to run them on the proxy-kernel.  This is performed by default using the riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc compiler.  If you are going to use the riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc compiler, you must either pass `-static` or you must run it on the Linux kernel.

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o asm_test asm_test.c [or...]
$ riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -static -o asm_test asm_test.c 
$ spike pk asm_test
```

---

In more detail, how I debugged this before I remembered the above limitation:

By running `$ spike -d pk asm_test 2> output.txt`, we can see the trace of the program:

```
<snippet>
374618 : core   0: 0x0000000000800320 (0x00002197) auipc   gp, 0x2                  
374619 : core   0: 0x0000000000800324 (0xc9818193) addi    gp, gp, -872             
374620 : core   0: 0x0000000000800328 (0x00050793) mv      a5, a0                   
374621 : core   0: 0x000000000080032c (0x00000517) auipc   a0, 0x0                  
374622 : core   0: 0x0000000000800330 (0x10450513) addi    a0, a0, 260              
374623 : core   0: 0x0000000000800334 (0x00013583) ld      a1, 0(sp)                
374624 : core   0: 0x0000000000800338 (0x00810613) addi    a2, sp, 8                
374625 : core   0: 0x000000000080033c (0xff017113) andi    sp, sp, -16              
374626 : core   0: 0x0000000000800340 (0x00000697) auipc   a3, 0x0                  
374627 : core   0: 0x0000000000800344 (0x14468693) addi    a3, a3, 324              
374628 : core   0: 0x0000000000800348 (0x00000717) auipc   a4, 0x0                  
374629 : core   0: 0x000000000080034c (0x1cc70713) addi    a4, a4, 460              
374630 : core   0: 0x0000000000800350 (0x00010813) mv      a6, sp                   
374631 : core   0: 0x0000000000800354 (0xfbdff06f) j       pc - 0x44                
374632 : core   0: 0x0000000000800310 (0x00001e17) auipc   t3, 0x1                  
374633 : core   0: 0x0000000000800314 (0x498e3e03) ld      t3, 1176(t3)             
374634 : core   0: 0x0000000000800318 (0x000e0367) jalr    t1, t3, 0                
374635 : core   0: 0x00000000008002e0 (0x00001397) auipc   t2, 0x1                  
374636 : core   0: 0x00000000008002e4 (0x41c30333) sub     t1, t1, t3               
374637 : core   0: 0x00000000008002e8 (0x4b03be03) ld      t3, 1200(t2)             
374638 : core   0: 0x00000000008002ec (0xfd430313) addi    t1, t1, -44              
374639 : core   0: 0x00000000008002f0 (0x4b038293) addi    t0, t2, 1200             
374640 : core   0: 0x00000000008002f4 (0x00135313) srli    t1, t1, 1                
374641 : core   0: 0x00000000008002f8 (0x0082b283) ld      t0, 8(t0)                
374642 : core   0: 0x00000000008002fc (0x000e0067) jr      t3                       
374643 : core   0: exception trap_instruction_access_fault, epc 0xfffffffffffffffe  
374644 core   0: 0x0000000000000100 (0x34011173) csrrw   sp, mscratch, sp           
374645 : core   0: 0x0000000000000104 (0x04a13823) sd      a0, 80(sp)               
374646 : core   0: 0x0000000000000108 (0x04b13c23) sd      a1, 88(sp)
```

If you objdump `asm_test`, you'll see that it's in `_start`, then `__libc_start_main`, then `__libc_start_main@plt` (0x800310), and then `_PROCEDURE_LINKAGE_TABLE_` (0x8002e0).

From there, it attempts a `jr`, which jumps to `0xfffffffffffffffe`, which is a misaligned fetch address. Hence the crash.

Comment: Thank you Chris yes as you mentioned i was executing it with pk. Id like to know how to run programs on risk-linux. Im using the zed board zynq, so do i boot riscv-linux on the zed board and run my binary on that. What is the syntax for it??

Comment: Yes. Please read the documentation (README in https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq).